# Read value from specific row and column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, sh

I have csv file in this format:

```
1 value1
2 value2
3 value3
```

I can also define it like this (if it is more convenient)

```
column1,column2
1,value1
2,value2
3,value3
```

I should write a shell script in order to match value from the first column and take value from that row from the second column value.
So for example, I have variable `var`
If var is equal to `1` then take and use (or print) `value1`.
If value is 2 take value2 and so on.
Number of rows is limited to 5.
Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: use grep and cut like so: `var=1 ; grep "^${var}" yourfile.txt | cut -d',' -f2`

Comment: Hi Red. For what purposes is this used  "^1"? how to match with my variable which will be read within the script? Thanks

Comment: the `^` mean match the start of a line. So `^1` means match line that starts with 1

Comment: Hi Red. but what if my value2 for example is something like this "1.1.1". Does it mean if I grep it with value "1" it will grep me the frst row (because of the first row first column value) but also and second row (because it is similar to second row second column value )? thanks

Comment: try it and see.

Comment: Thank you it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk is your friend here:

```
$ cat input.txt
1 value1
2 value2
3 value3 
$ awk -v key=1 '$1 == key { print $2 }' input.txt
value1
$ awk -v key=2 '$1 == key { print $2 }' input.txt
value2
```

etc. Just replace the `key=1` with `key=$var`.